# When to use whence instead of hence

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

I've come across instances where I felt using both was just fine. The dictionary definition doesn't provide much clarity either. Could someone please clarify the differences between the two?

Comment: This is far too open-ended a question. You’re going to have to tell us what it is you think those both mean, and give examples of how you would like to use them, and then explain just what part of all that you are having a problem with.

Comment: You will never understand these words until you realize there are three sets of three: *hence, thence, whence; here, there, where; hither, thither, whither*.  The three “starts” of *wh-, th-, h-* combine ***meaningfully*** with the three “ends” of *-ence, -here, -ither* to form 9 distinct and special words.

Comment: @tchrist: It's three sets of four -- don't forget _when, then, now_; and it's  a [paradigm](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.html), so it's really a form/function mapping, a "double articulation", as Saussure called it.

Comment: @JohnLawler You’re right that I forgot *when* and *then* and . . . and . . . um, and *hen*. :)  Yeah, yeah: I know you can find faint vestiges of adverbial *hen* if you look hard enough: “OE. *hionane, hionan = OS. and OHG. hinana, hinan, MDutch henen, MHG. hinnen, hinne, Ger. hinnen; cf. also OHG. hina, MHG. hine, hin, Ger. hin, MLG. hen, MDutch hēne, hin, Dutch heen; adverbial formations from root hi- ‘this’, of he pron. The various OE. types gave a great number of forms in ME., **all which are now obsolete,** leaving only the later extended form henne-s, hen-s, hence, and the Sc. hyne.”

Comment: The point of the quiz question I linked to, of course, was that the irregularity of _now_ illustrates the difference between the formal paradigm (where it stands out like a sore thumb) and the functional paradigm (where it's entirely unexceptionable, indeed more regular than many of the modern meanings of the words in the paradigm). I've often thought of extending this paradigm to demonstratives and other interrogative/relatives, but that'd take more than two dimensions and you can't do that in a 10-minute quiz.

Comment: Double articulation in Saussure means signifier and signified, starting at phoneme level. I personally would not invoke that here. Everything in human language has double articulation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "Lift thine eyes to the mountains,
>
> **whence** cometh help.
>
> Thy help cometh from the Lord,
>
> the maker of heaven and earth"  (Psalm 121:1 KJV)

*Whence* is an old-fashioned word for *where*, or *from where*.

*Hence*, on the  other hand, is best illustrated with a bit of algebra:  X  > Y; Z  < Y; **hence**, X  > Z.  *Hence* means therefore.

> "I'm sorry, but I simply ran out of time; hence, I couldn't pick up your dry cleaning for you."

"Then said they unto him, Tell us, we pray thee, for whose cause this evil is upon us; What is thine occupation? and **whence** comest thou? what is thy country? and of what people art thou?"

> Jonah's shipmates wondered what he had done to bring the calamity of a great storm upon them.  Since he was a stranger, they simply assumed it was his fault.  Hence, they asked him, "Hey, from **whence** comest thou?"  See Jonah 1:8 KJV.

Comment: +1 for the algebra. So does that mean whence shouldn't be used in modern language?

Comment: Hm, it’s much more complicated than that. *Hence* means “from here/now/this point”, while *whence* means “from where/which”. Consider: “Vengeance calls me **hence**, but even were it otherwise I would not dwell longer in the same land with the kin of my father’s slayer and of the thief of my treasure.”“‘Go **hence,** ’ he said, ‘unto a swift and bitter death.’” “Yet if there be any on whom the shadow of our curse has not yet fallen, I should find at least a few to follow me, and should not go **hence** as a beggar that is thrust from the gates.” “Yet we must move **hence** without more delay.”

Comment: Not to (not) mention: *The worthies of Bree will be discussing it a hundred years **hence**.*

Comment: It's part of a dead paradigm. I used to use it as [an exam question](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.html).

Comment: @tofu_bacon:  Not unless you are quoting Shakespeare or the King James Version of the Bible.  You will hear the occasional "hence," even in modern language usage, though not likely among hoi polloi.

Answer (score 6):

As @tchrist comments, you need to consider the *three sets of three:...*

> here, there, where;
>    hence, thence, whence;
>    hither, thither, whither

***But*** in practice the last set are pretty dated/archaic forms in *all* contexts, and the middle set are normally only used metaphorically today.

Once you stop to think about the fact that the usage is *metaphoric*, it should become clear. Here are some written instances from Google Books...

> ([here is] some stated fact) [**hence** we derive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22commenced%20doing%20something%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22hence%20we%20derive%22&oq=%22hence%20we%20derive%22&gs_l=serp.3...6785.6785.2.7038.1.1.0.0.0.0.45.45.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.-cbfNrPIi_k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1263&bih=866) (some other fact) *(i.e. - "from this fact here")*
>    (some statement) [**thence** we derive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22commenced%20doing%20something%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22and%20thence%20we%20derive%22&oq=%22and%20thence%20we%20derive%22&gs_l=serp.3...235628.236787.3.237169.4.4.0.0.0.0.81.250.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.bjZNFgxKNRM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1263&bih=866) (some fact) *(i.e. - "from that statement you just read **there**")*
>    (some statement) [**whence** we derive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22commenced%20doing%20something%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22and%20whence%20we%20derive%22&oq=%22and%20whence%20we%20derive%22&gs_l=serp.3...313343.313907.4.314418.2.2.0.0.0.0.129.174.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.f2Nhkqk19h8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k&fp=93f637ceeafc3c9d&biw=1263&bih=866) (some fact) *(i.e. - whence=wherefrom)*

You won't come across *whence* so often these days, but (as I hope those examples illustrate) it can sometimes be used in contexts where either or both the others would be perfectly acceptable.

---

Since the usages are all metaphoric, the "location" of the "statement" (or thing referenced by the statement) is somewhat uncertain. In speech/physical space, the difference between *"There it is!"* and *"Here it is!"* may simply depend on whether you're pointing a finger or spreading your hands as you speak.

But at any point within a written text, *here* could encompass the entire book you're reading, and *there* could mean just the previous sentence or clause. And *where/wherefrom/whence* can always refer to anything written previously (normally, the *immediately-preceding* statement).

---

To sum it all up - if you're not sure which to use, stick with the most common form *(hence)*. If there's a strong sense of *from **there*** or *from **where*** in your context, use *thence* or *whence*.

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume you know what *here*, *there*, and *where* mean.

*Hence*, *thence* and *whence* mean *from here*, *from there* and *from where*.

*Hither*, *thither* and *whither* mean *to here*, *to there* and *to where*.

Answer (score 0):

"Whence" means "from where." It's not a substitute for "hence." Its meaning is nowhere to "hence."

Ex:

*Whence do you come?*

It means, "from where do you come?"

Hope I answered your question.

I recommend the following sites for great grammar info:

http://englishisducksoup.com

http://www.queens-english-society.com